# Super simple Hasse diagram using LaTex

Tags: diagrams, draw, lattice

I am not a LaTex expert, but I should generate a Hasse diagram (which describes a lattice) that reflects this (simple) figure:
[image]

Sorry if the drawing is a little bit crooked, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), by which you show what you try so far and where is your problem. As such your question is of "do-this-for-me" question ... and I will suggest to close it as to broad.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is based on manually adjusted of node placements using Ti*K*z.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (l1) at (0,0){\ldots};
\node (l2) at (5,0){\ldots};
\foreach \x/\sub in{1/i,2/j,3/k,4/l}{
\node (V\sub) at (\x,0){$V_{\sub}$};}
\node [white,circle,inner sep=5pt,label={[rotate=180]right:{\color{black}$\perp$}}] (T1) at (2.5,1.5){};
\draw (l1.north)--(T1.180);
\draw (l2.north)--(T1.0);
\draw (Vi.north)--(T1.210);
\draw (Vj.north)--(T1.265);
\draw (Vk.north)--(T1.270);
\draw (Vl.north)--(T1.-30);

\node [white,circle](T2) at (2.5,-1.5){\color{black}$\perp$};
\draw (l1.south)--(T2.180);
\draw (l2.south)--(T2.0);
\draw (Vi.south)--(T2.120);
\draw (Vj.south)--(T2.95);
\draw (Vk.south)--(T2.90);
\draw (Vl.south)--(T2.30);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One alternative:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm and 10mm]
  \node[circle](Top){$\top$};
  \node[circle,below=of Top](Bot){$\bot$};
  \node[anchor=center] (Vj) at ($(Top)!0.5!(Bot) + (-5mm,0mm)$){\strut$V_j$};
  \node[left=of Vj.center,anchor=center](Vi){\strut$V_i$};
  \node[left=of Vi.center,anchor=center](Ldots){\strut$\cdots$};
  \node[right=of Vj.center,anchor=center](Vk){\strut$V_k$};
  \node[right=of Vk.center,anchor=center](Vl){\strut$V_l$};
  \node[right=of Vl.center,anchor=center](Rdots){\strut$\cdots$};
  \foreach \n in {Ldots,Vi,Vj,Vk,Vl,Rdots}{
    \draw(Top)--(\n)--(Bot);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple tikz-cd code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

{\boldmath
    \tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style={dash}}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny] 
    & & \ar{dll} \dlar \dar \boldsymbol{\top} \drar \ar{drr}\ar{drrr}\\
    \dots &V_i & V_j & V_k & V_l & \dots \\
    & & \ar{ull} \ular \uar \bot \urar \ar{urr}\ar{urrr}
\end{tikzcd}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:  Another code, with the `psmatrix` environment:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pst-node, multido}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

```
\begin{document}

{ \boldmath%
 \[ \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=3pt, rowsep=0.9cm, colsep =0.5cm,nodesep=3pt}
     \begin{psmatrix}
      & &[name=T] \top\psspan{2}\\
      ... &V_i & V_j & V_k & V_l & ... \\%
       & & [name=B]\bot \psspan{2}
     %%% node connections
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{\ncline{T}{2,\i}\ncline{B}{2,\i}}
     \end{psmatrix}
     \]
 }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An arguably much simpler solution with `tikz-cd`, which is symmetric and in which the user does not have to enter tons of arrows by hand. All you need to do is to say

```
\begin{tikzcd}[Hasse matrix] 
\dots &V_i & V_j & V_k & V_\ell &  \dots 
\end{tikzcd}
```

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{Hasse matrix/.style={column sep=tiny,execute at end picture={
\path ([yshift=3em]\tikzcdmatrixname.north) node(t) {$\top$}
 ([yshift=-3em]\tikzcdmatrixname.south) node(b) {$\bot$};
\foreach \X in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
{\draw (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\X) -- (t) (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\X) -- (b);}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[Hasse matrix] 
    \dots &V_i & V_j & V_k & V_\ell &  \dots 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]